# Based on the condition how to create StringBuffers and append data to it

Tags: java

My ArrayList contains list of values in String Format

The Data inside ArrayList will be this way

```
ArrayList<String> my_list = new ArrayList<String>();

   my_list.add("Today Date");
    my_list.add("Some Content1");
    my_list.add("*****");
    my_list.add("Some Content2");
    my_list.add("Some Content3");
    my_list.add("*****");
    my_list.add("Some Content5");
    my_list.add("Some Content6");
    my_list.add("*****");
    my_list.add("Some Content8");
```

I am trying to create one sepearte StringBuffer for content present after the seperator *****

I have tried this way

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> my_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray jsarray = new JSONArray();
        my_list.add("Today Date");
        my_list.add("Some Content1");
        my_list.add("*****");
        my_list.add("Some Content2");
        my_list.add("Some Content3");
        my_list.add("*****");
        my_list.add("Some Content5");
        my_list.add("Some Content6");
        my_list.add("*****");
        my_list.add("Some Content8");
      for(int i=0;i<my_list.size();i++)
        {
            String linedata = my_list.get(i);
            if(linedata.equals("*****"))
            {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append(linedata);
                jsarray.put(sb.toString());
            }
        }
      System.out.println(jsarray);
    }
}
```

The output i got from this is

```
["*****","*****","*****"]
```

Where as the expected output should be this way

```
["Today Date Some Content1", "Some Content2 Some Content3", "Some Content5 Some Content6", "Some Content8"]
```

Could you please tell me where exactly i am making mistake and how to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the exact opposite of your intent; you are ignoring the content and adding the "*****" separators.  Incidentally, if you don't need to be thread safe here, you can use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Instead of creating a `StringBuilder` every time you encounter the separator, you need to have a `StringBuilder` created and ready before you encounter the separator.  If you encounter the separator, then don't append to it; convert it to a string, place it in your array, and clear it.  Also make sure to place the last string in your array after your loop is finished, after the last separator.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<my_list.size();i++)
{
    String linedata = my_list.get(i);
    if(linedata.equals("*****"))
    {
        jsarray.put(sb.toString());
        sb.setLength(0);  // clear
    }
    else
    {
        sb.append(linedata);
    }
}
jsarray.put(sb.toString());  // last one!
```